USDT Transfer Working on Website, Fails When Done Through Mobile Wallet
// Define the Jetton transfer payload
const buildJettonTransferPayload = (receiverAddress, amount) => {
  
  const depositAmount = toNano(amount); // Convert the amount to nanoTON
  
  // Check if receiverAddress is valid
  let parsedReceiverAddress;
  try {
    parsedReceiverAddress = Address.parse(receiverAddress);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Invalid receiver address");
  }
  
  // Construct the Jetton transfer payload
  const body = beginCell()
    .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32) // Operation ID for Jetton transfer (USDT)
    .storeUint(0, 64) // Query ID
    .storeCoins(depositAmount) // Deposit amount (in nanoTON)
    .storeAddress(parsedReceiverAddress) // Receiver address
    .storeMaybeRef(null) // No custom payload
    .storeCoins(toNano(0.03)) // Forward TON amount (0.03 TON for fees)
    .storeMaybeRef(beginCell().storeStringTail('Transfer USDT').endCell()) // Forward payload
    .endCell();

  return body;
};

const myTransaction = (receiverAddress, amount) => ({
  validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360, // Transaction expiry
  messages: [
    {
      address: usdtContractAddress, // USDT Jetton contract address
      amount: toNano(0.03), // Commission fee (0.03 TON)
      payload: buildJettonTransferPayload(receiverAddress, amount).toBoc().toString("base64"), // Base64 encoded Jetton transfer payload
    },
  ],
});

This payload successfully transfers USDT from one wallet to another(used tonkeeper) on browser but fails when done through mobile wallet app like tonkeeper
There could have been an error made when creating the payload or boc. The transfer occurs and a hash is also generated (by decoding the boc), but the USDT does not transfers (it indicates failure prior to the transfer operation to be performed). I want user to allow perform transaction from browser as well as mobile wallet and also want to verify that usdt are transferred successfully!
